# Merge two colum of a data frame with particulars cases R

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I have a data frame which looks like that :

| MANUAL.ID | AUTO.ID |
| --- | --- |
| Barbar | Barbar |
| Barbar |  |
| Barbar | Pippip |
| Barbar | Pippip,Hypsav |
| Pippip | Barbar |
|  | Barbar,Pippip |

Basically I whould merge the both columns in a single called species and obtain this kind of result :

| species |
| --- |
| Barbar,Barbar |
| Barbar |
| Barbar,Pippip |
| Barbar,Pippip,Hypsav |
| Pippip,Barbar |
| Barbar,Pippip |

What can I do to get the result ?

Comment: have you tried `paste`? in a `mutate` or `transform`, one can do `species = sub("^,|,$", "", paste(MANUAL.ID, AUTO.ID, sep = ","))`

Comment: could you be more specific on what you want?

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `paste` with `apply`

```
data.frame(species = apply(df, 1, function(x) 
  ifelse(any(x == ""), paste(x, collapse=""), paste(x, collapse=","))))
               species
1        Barbar,Barbar
2               Barbar
3        Barbar,Pippip
4 Barbar,Pippip,Hypsav
5        Pippip,Barbar
6        Barbar,Pippip
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(MANUAL.ID = c("Barbar", "Barbar", "Barbar", "Barbar", 
"Pippip", ""), AUTO.ID = c("Barbar", "", "Pippip", "Pippip,Hypsav", 
"Barbar", "Barbar,Pippip")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```